# mvn clean install results in surefire error

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have not made any changes to my projects, but they are all resulting in errors when I run `mvn clean install` or `mvn package`

The projects run fine when I run them in Spring Tool Suit (Pretty much Eclipse)

Below is from one of my projects

```
arya@2OC-2OE:~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelperAPI 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ HelperAPI ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ HelperAPI ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ HelperAPI ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelperAPI ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelperAPI ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ HelperAPI ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.411 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-31T10:50:53-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/294M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project HelperAPI: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/surefire/surefirebooter3828813415223070401.jar /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/surefire 2018-10-31T10-50-53_064-jvmRun1 surefire8224915599358179621tmp surefire_0529698540830278579tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/surefire/surefirebooter3828813415223070401.jar /home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/HelperAPI/target/surefire 2018-10-31T10-50-53_064-jvmRun1 surefire8224915599358179621tmp surefire_0529698540830278579tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.helperapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelperAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>HelperAPI</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.iakovlev</groupId>
            <artifactId>timeshape</artifactId>
            <version>2018d.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide your pom?

Comment: @CristianoBombazar added

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Comment: I had this recently - had to roll back my Java.

Comment: @Kieveli can you confirm if this is a Bug? I'm having this issue now

Comment: It certainly was a problem for me, but I haven't been back to the code base since.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to add this. When I had the same issue, that worked for me:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @EdwinDiaz-Mendez What link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010200/maven-surefire-could-not-find-forkedbooter-class

Comment: This did work, the build is successfull but is stil failing the tests. And the main problem is that surefire-plugin does not log the individual test results. Nothing on the log files too. Using Spring Boot with Jenkins on a Docker container

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of people reporting this issue, it's a problem answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016532/3709338

Basically, it's a bug in [OpenJDK](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911925) and the fix is to either downgrade, use Oracle Java or set a system property (see bug for notes)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (openjdk11, maven 3.6, docker on windows 10) the solution was to update maven-surefire-plugin from 2.21.0 to 2.22.2.

The jvmRun1.dump just contained "Killing self fork JVM. Maven process died."

Answer (score 0):

Just change the your "maven-surefire-plugin" version and this error wil get solved. Thanks !!!

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: I’m glad to hear you found an answer here on the Stack Overflow community, but please be sure to reserve the _Answers_ feature for actual answers. While I’m sure other contributors appreciate your gratitude, **the best way to express that gratitude is to upvote their answer**. You’ll need to gain some reputation here on Stack Overflow before you’re able to do that; you can do that by suggesting edits to answers or contributing useful posts to the community.